# Application error with Heroku after deployment

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, npm, yarnpkg

After having deployed my app with success I clicked on "Open app" and I see this error:

```
Application error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command
heroku logs --tail
```

Link with error https://fcrg.herokuapp.com/

But it does work correctly in localhost with yarn dev cli

package.json for backend app :

```
{
  "name": "site-web-france",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "heroku-postbuild": "cd client && npm install && npm install --only=dev --no-shrinkwrap && npm run build",
    "client": "cd client && yarn start",
    "server": "nodemon server.js",
    "dev": "concurrently --kill-others-on-fail \"yarn server\" \"yarn client\"",
    "dev:server": "cd client && yarn build && cd .. && yarn start",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "heroku-postbuild": "cd client && npm install && npm install --only=dev --no-shrinkwrap && npm run build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "mongodb": "^3.1.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.2.6",
    "react-scripts": "^1.1.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^3.5.0"
  }
}
```

I think this problem is because of "yarn", what do you think ?

tutorial followed :
https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-make-create-react-app-work-with-a-node-backend-api-7c5c48acb1b0

Comment: Have you tried to run $ heroku local  in order to test locally. Because if run it locally before deploying you get more clear error message. here is the link https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-local

Comment: I don't have heroku cli, I can't have for the moment

Comment: You should probably try to  install heroku- cli if possible and   test it locally otherwise it would be difficult to find out the problem.

Comment: @crg did you find any solution for this problem? I m getting the same error

Comment: I have the same problem with node.js + ExpressJS application. I tried to test the app locally as per the first @sedar comment, at first, it didn't work properly cause I didn't install dependencies, after running npm i and re-run the local test command, It is working fine locally but online I get (cannot get /) error

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that the application port is *NOT* hard-coded like:

`app.listen(3000, ...)`

It can cause problems with Heroku. Instead try using the environment variable `PORT`:

`app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, ...)`

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you Ajay but that is my variable of port `const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;` and that the listen `app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));`